# Javascript - A resizing scroll header with overwrite when in mobile viewport

Tags: javascript, function, mobile, scroll, viewport

I am trying to do a header that change the font size when scrolling that is working.
But because of the font size is so big i does not workout for mobile devices.

here is the code:

```
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 800) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "5em";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "10em";
  } if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/){
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "2em";
  }
}
```

Is there anyone who knows how to make this work or another way to say that the code should not work when on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Just which part is working that is fine, now for mobile you can add one more check by media-query with window.matchmedia, it will find your window width and change font according to your mobile., let spose your max mobile-width 360px ,then do as given below :-

```
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 360px)")
myFunction(x) 
x.addListener(myFunction)

function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { 
     document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "2em";
  } else {
  scrollFunction()
  }
}
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 800 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 800) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "5em";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = "10em";
  }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for you .
Thanks
Hamza

Comment: Thank you this was what i needed. Is it important that the "max With" us written before the other code? Or does this not matter?

Comment: Sorry, after trying it out there is still some problem with the code. It will not change en desktop after scrolling 800px. :-(

Comment: Hey , please can you post your code anywhere & provide me link , I can resolve that after check your code and problem.  Yes max-width is important for mobile view. If it is helpful for you ,please vote my answer

Comment: Hi. http://willyorskovarchive.com So i uploaded it to this website it is the big header at the front page.